# Blender with multiple monitors

Tags: blender, task-management, kwin

I run blender with multiple monitors and each window creates a new Icon in my taskbar, in comparison Gimp which has multiple windows does not. is there a way to fix this?

I am running KDE desktop. I also hide the windows decoration on extra windows, which does not work on blender as when I set one window it sets them all like that.

Comment: I've always found it easier to resize one window to fill both monitors. I save my startup file with dual-monitor enhanced screens and rarely use load ui from external files.